# Issue downloading JSON objects in iOS

Tags: ios, json

In my iOS app I use JSON to upload MySQL objects.

This is the celForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Lista_Actividades_TableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell ==nil){
        cell = [[Lista_Actividades_TableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.dia_label.hidden = NO;
    cell.minutos_label.hidden = NO;

    cell.hora_label.hidden = NO;
    cell.mes_label.hidden = NO;
     cell.puntos_label.hidden = NO;

    NSString *hora = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hora_evento"];
    NSString *minutos  = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"minutos_evento"];


        if ([hora isEqualToString:@"0"]){
            hora = @"00";
        }
        if ([minutos isEqualToString:@"0"]){
            minutos = @"00";



        }


    if ([ [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hora_evento"] isEqualToString:@"0"] && [[[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"minutos_evento"] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        cell.hora_label.hidden = YES;
        cell.puntos_label.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.hora_label.text = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hora_evento"];
    }
    if ([[[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hora_evento"] isEqualToString:@"0"] && [[[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"minutos_evento"] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        cell.minutos_label.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.minutos_label.text = minutos;
    }





    if ([ [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"dia_evento"] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        cell.dia_label.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
         cell.dia_label.text = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"dia_evento"];
    }

        NSString *mes_evento = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"mes_evento"];
        int value = [mes_evento intValue];





    if ([ [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"mes_evento"] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        cell.mes_label.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case 1:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"ENERO";
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"FEBRERO";
                break;
            case 3:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"MARZO";
                break;
            case 4:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"ABRIL";
                break;
            case 5:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"MAYO";
                break;
            case 6:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"JUNIO";
                break;
            case 7:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"JULIO";
                break;
            case 8:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"AGOSTO";
                break;
            case 9:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"SEPTIEMBRE";
                break;
            case 10:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"OCTUBRE";
                break;
            case 11:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"NOVIEMBRE";
                break;
            case 12:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"DICIEMBRE";
                break;
            default:
                cell.mes_label.text =@"SIN MES";
                break;
        }
    }







     cell.titulo_label.text = [[[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"titulo_evento"] uppercaseString];

    NSString *lugar = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"lugar_evento"];
    if ([lugar isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        NSLog(@"LUGAR AQUI ES=%@",lugar);
        cell.lugar_label.text = @" ";
    }
    else {
    cell.lugar_label.text = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"lugar_evento"];
    }

    NSMutableString *logo = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"hidden here"];
    NSString *imageURL = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imagen_evento"];






    if(imageURL != nil && ![imageURL isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    {
        [logo appendString:imageURL];
        NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logo];
        NSData *logoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:logoURL];

        cell.imagen_label.image = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
    }
    else{
        cell.imagen_label.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image-512.png"];
    }





    return cell;
}
```

There are 45 objects, and always at the same object, the app crashes with following error:

```
URL = ACTteatro.jpg
mujergrancanaria(4031,0x4f9e1d4) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region securely
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mujergrancanaria(4031,0x4f9e1d4) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region securely
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
```

I have developed apps that download more JSON objects, pictures and text and have never experienced this issue.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download your image in background task, doing network operation in main thread cause verious problem:

For downloading image in background task you can do this:

```
if(imageURL != nil && ![imageURL isEqual:[NSNull null]])
{
    [logo appendString:imageURL];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logo];
        NSData *logoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:logoURL];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (logoData.length) {
                cell.imagen_label.image = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
            }else{
                cell.imagen_label.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image-512.png"];
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Thank you Rashasd, implementing your proposal makes the images download faster, but at the same object the app doesn't crash, but stops working, it freezes.

Comment: It finally crashes... :(

Comment: the same as before: mujergrancanaria(4757,0x4fde1d4) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region securely

Comment: @ModestoVasco> i am pretty sure your app has memory leakage. Can you monitor how much memory you are using?

Comment: At the crash instant, 5.7 Mb

Comment: @ModestoVasco> Did you tried cleaning the project? or restarting your XCode?

Comment: Yes Rashad, and no success.

Comment: @ModestoVasco> Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67890/discussion-between-rashad-and-modesto-vasco).

Comment: This will load images to the wrong cell during scrolling.

Comment: Thank you Rashad, I have accepted your answer, the images are now loaded faster and without exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You should download images asynchronously and save them in object and reuse them.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"venue";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        Venue *venue = ((Venue * )self.venues[indexPath.row]);
        if (venue.userImage) {
            cell.imageView.image = venue.image;
        } else {
            // set default user image while image is being downloaded
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"batman.png"];

            // download the image asynchronously
            [self downloadImageWithURL:venue.url completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
                if (succeeded) {
                    // change the image in the cell
                    cell.imageView.image = image;

                    // cache the image for use later (when scrolling up)
                    venue.image = image;
                }
            }];
        }
    }



    - (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image))completionBlock
    {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                   if ( !error )
                                   {
                                        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                        completionBlock(YES,image);
                                    } else{
                                        completionBlock(NO,nil);
                                    }
                               }];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I know, its only a tag to know the image name...it is inside NSLog.

Comment: Ok can you share the whole url here.

Comment: The URL is not the problem, up to the object that crashes the app, all pictures are shown.

Comment: I have removed the line: NSLog(@"URL = %@",imageURL); and the issue is still there.

Comment: are you saving your downloaded images and using them again on reuse of cell??

Comment: And where in your proposal should I put the path to the image?

Comment: This will load images to the wrong cell during scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are downloading data from the Internet, and converting it to an image, all on the main thread:

```
NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logo];
NSData *logoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:logoURL];
cell.imagen_label.image = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
```

Don't do that. Return your cell as quickly as possible. Download and process the image asynchronously. There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow that show various approaches, and even [open source libraries](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) designed to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you,I will try also the answer from Rashad

Comment: Would you mind explaining me the right method. I mean, for every object the cellForRowAtIndex method is called, that means that the data are put on the cell, and the image is downloaded from internet and put on the image view container, right? But as I have done my code, the load is too high and the app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

try using SDWebImages for image upload .

Comment: Thank you,I will try also the answer from Rashad.